# Looking for Streaming Spark ML example with raw data as input

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am newbie to Spark ML. **I am looking for Streaming ml example with raw data as input (I mean raw String delimited data, not the vectorized data).**
I tried to look at most of the forums to find the similar example, I couldn't find any.

So, I approached the following way for Streaming Kmeans on Spark 1.6 (Streaming Kmeans still works on vector data rather than dataframes), 
But I am not sure, if this is the right way.

- Input Dstream records from Kafka, I am converting that to Dataframe.
- Built a pre data pipeline to read the columns I need to convert that to vectors.
- Since in every Stream batch, data is different and Vector length may differ, So, I am using Tokenizer and HashingTF to maintain constant vector length.
- Also in each Stream batch, to identify the vector belongs to which row, I have assigned the row number and sending that to Streaming Kmeans algorithm
- And after getting the cluster ID for each row, I am joining the cluster ID to the row data to get the final predicted dataframe.

Now I have doubts in the way I implemented this.

- To my understanding, using the HashingTF with fixed vector length (setNumFeatures) will not solve my issue, the reason being the same vectors may repeat again, if the combination of vector is less than the number of rows in a single batch (hard-coded  it to 200 right now in my below code)
- Also I tried StringIndexer with OneHotEncoder for generation of vectors, but I see vector length is differing for each batch.
- Since we have way a head assign RandomCenters for StreamingKMeans, I have to know the vector length prior to my execution (for my testing data and columns, since I getting vector length as 800, I hard-coded it for now for testing)
- Though we have to send training vectors with all combinations of data separately for train the model, right now I am using both the training and testing vectors as same.

Can someone guide me or share me some streaming ml example with raw data as input ?

```
import com.common.Configuration._
import com.twitter.bijection.Injection
import com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs
import kafka.serializer.{DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder}
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext, SaveMode}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineStage}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

import scala.util.Try;

object KafkaDataConsumer {

  //localOrCluster=l streamBatchSeconds=2 locationToSaveStream=tmp3 isAvroTopic=text hiveTableName= modelName=streamkmeans hiveORFile=file locationToSaveModelData=tmp1 predictedDataLocation=tmp2 labelCol=salary nonStringCols= stringCols=workclass,age,education_num,hours_per_week csvOrHiveForTrain=data/mllib/adult.csv csvOrHiveForTest=data/mllib/adult.csv noOfNodes=10 noOfIter=10 locationToStorePmml=pmmlfolder runMLPipeline=true isOverwriteDataOk=no

  // Setting the logs levels
  setLogLevels(Level.WARN, Seq("spark", "org", "akka"))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    executeStreamdata(args)

  }

  def executeStreamdata(args: Array[String]) {

    val namedArgs = getNamedArgs(args)
    val localOrCluster = namedArgs("localOrCluster")
    val streamBatchSeconds = namedArgs("streamBatchSeconds").toInt
    val isAvroTopic = namedArgs("isAvroTopic").equalsIgnoreCase("avro")
    val kafkaBrokerList = kafkaConfig.getString("kafkaBrokerList")
    val kafkaTopicList =
      if (isAvroTopic)
        kafkaConfig.getString("TOPIC1_NAME")
      else
        kafkaConfig.getString("TOPIC2_NAME")

    val SCHEMA =
      if (isAvroTopic)
        kafkaConfig.getString("TOPIC1_SCHEMA")
      else
        kafkaConfig.getString("TOPIC2_SCHEMA")

    val labelCol = namedArgs("labelCol")
    val nonStringCols = namedArgs("nonStringCols")
    val stringCols = namedArgs("stringCols")
    val noOfNodes = namedArgs("noOfNodes").toInt
    val predictedDataLocation = namedArgs("predictedDataLocation")

    val sc = getSparkContext(localOrCluster, "kafka stream application")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(streamBatchSeconds))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val topicsSet = kafkaTopicList.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaBrokerList)

    //Read Stream records either as AVRO or String
    val dStreamRecords =
      if (isAvroTopic) {
        val parser = new Schema.Parser
        val schema = parser.parse(SCHEMA)
        val recordInjection: Injection[GenericRecord, Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)

        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
          .map(message => recordInjection.invert(message._2).get.toString)
      }
      else {
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2)
      }

    println("Executing Streaming KMeans")

    //Pipeline for generating the label, features vector using StringTokenizer and HashFunction based on input label Columns, string and nonString Columns
    val pipelineStagesWithAssembler = buildDataPrepPipeLine(sqlContext, labelCol, stringCols, nonStringCols, true)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(pipelineStagesWithAssembler)
    var vectorsDFSchema:StructType = null

    def createDFFromDStream(rdd: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {
      if (isAvroTopic)
        sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
      else
        sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map(x => Row.fromSeq(x.split(",").toSeq)), createSchemaFrmStrDelValues(SCHEMA))
    }

    val vectorDataWithRowNum = dStreamRecords.transform(rdd=>{
      //Create dataframe from the input data
      val dataframe = createDFFromDStream(rdd)

      //Get the pipeline model
      val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataframe)

      //Get label, features vectors in the DataF
      val vectorsDF = pipelineModel.transform(dataframe)

      //get the row number for the dataframe
      val vectorsDFWithRowNum = dfWithRowIndexUsingRDD(vectorsDF)
      vectorsDFSchema = StructType(vectorsDFWithRowNum.schema.filter(!_.dataType.toString.contains("Vector")))

      //Get row number, vectors , row data
      val reqData = vectorsDFWithRowNum.map(row => {
        (row.getAs[Long]("row_num"), row.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]("features"), row)
      })
      reqData
    })

    // get train data(vector) , test data (row number or index, vector), row data (row number or index, row data)
    val (dStreamTrainVector, dStreamTestVector, rowData) = (vectorDataWithRowNum.map(_._2), vectorDataWithRowNum.map(data=>(data._1, data._2)), vectorDataWithRowNum.map(data=>(data._1, data._3)))

    // Need to Fix the Random Centers hardcoded 800
    val model = new StreamingKMeans()
      .setK(noOfNodes)
      .setDecayFactor(1.0)
      .setRandomCenters(800, 0)

    // Train the Kmeans model
    model.trainOn(dStreamTrainVector)

    // Predict vales from the model
    val joinData = model.predictOnValues(dStreamTestVector).join(rowData)

    joinData.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
      val seqData = rdd.map(x=>{
        val id = x._1
        val clusterID = x._2._1
        val rowData = x._2._2.toSeq.filter(!_.isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector])
        Row.fromSeq(rowData :+ clusterID.toString)
      })

      val dfPredictions = sqlContext.createDataFrame(seqData, vectorsDFSchema.add("clusterID", StringType))
      dfPredictions.printSchema()
      dfPredictions.show()

      dfPredictions.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).save(predictedDataLocation)
    })

    ssc.start
    ssc.awaitTermination
  }

  private def buildOneHotPipeLine(colName:String, isStreamJob:Boolean = false):Array[PipelineStage] = {

    if(isStreamJob){
      val tokenizer = new org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer()
        .setInputCol(s"${colName}")
        .setOutputCol(s"${colName}_token")
      val hashingTF = new org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF()
        .setInputCol(s"${colName}_token")
        .setOutputCol(s"${colName}_hashFeature").setNumFeatures(200)

      Array(tokenizer, hashingTF)
    }else {
      val stringIndexer = new StringIndexer()
        .setInputCol(s"$colName")
        .setOutputCol(s"${colName}_index")

      val oneHotEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
        .setInputCol(s"${colName}")
        .setOutputCol(s"${colName}_onehotindex")

      Array(stringIndexer, oneHotEncoder)
    }
  }

  def buildDataPrepPipeLine(sqlContext: SQLContext, lableCol: String, stringCols: String, nonStringCols: String, isStreamJob:Boolean = false):Array[PipelineStage] = {

    var pipelineStagesforFeatures : Array[PipelineStage]= null
    var assemblerInputCols :Array[String] = null

    if(stringCols != null && !stringCols.isEmpty ){
      val stringColsArray = stringCols.split(",")

      if(pipelineStagesforFeatures != null) {
        pipelineStagesforFeatures = pipelineStagesforFeatures ++ stringColsArray.map(columnName => buildOneHotPipeLine(columnName, isStreamJob)).reduce(_ ++ _)
      }else{
        pipelineStagesforFeatures = stringColsArray.map(columnName => buildOneHotPipeLine(columnName, isStreamJob)).reduce(_++_)
      }

      if(assemblerInputCols != null) {
        assemblerInputCols = assemblerInputCols ++ stringColsArray.map(colName => if(isStreamJob) s"${colName}_hashFeature" else s"${colName}_onehotindex")
      }else{
        assemblerInputCols = stringColsArray.map(colName => if(isStreamJob) s"${colName}_hashFeature" else s"${colName}_onehotindex")
      }
    }

    if(nonStringCols != null && !nonStringCols.isEmpty ){
      val nonStringColsArray = nonStringCols.split(",")

      if(assemblerInputCols != null) {
        assemblerInputCols = assemblerInputCols ++ nonStringColsArray
      }else{
        assemblerInputCols = nonStringColsArray
      }
    }
    // Combine all the features and make it a single Feature
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(assemblerInputCols)
      .setOutputCol("features")


    var labelIndexer : StringIndexer= null
    if(lableCol != null && !lableCol.isEmpty){
      labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
      labelIndexer.setInputCol(lableCol)
      labelIndexer.setOutputCol("label")
    }

    val pipelineStagesWithAssembler =
      if(stringCols != null && !stringCols.isEmpty &&
        nonStringCols != null && !nonStringCols.isEmpty &&
        lableCol != null && !lableCol.isEmpty) {

        pipelineStagesforFeatures.toList ::: List(assembler,labelIndexer)

      }else if( stringCols != null && !stringCols.isEmpty &&
        lableCol != null && !lableCol.isEmpty){

        pipelineStagesforFeatures.toList ::: List(assembler,labelIndexer)

      } else if( nonStringCols != null && !nonStringCols.isEmpty &&
        lableCol != null && !lableCol.isEmpty){

        List(assembler,labelIndexer)

      }else if( stringCols != null && !stringCols.isEmpty &&
        nonStringCols != null && !nonStringCols.isEmpty){

        pipelineStagesforFeatures.toList ::: List(assembler)

      }else if( stringCols != null && !stringCols.isEmpty){

        pipelineStagesforFeatures.toList ::: List(assembler)

      }else{
        List(assembler)
      }

    pipelineStagesWithAssembler.toArray
  }

  def dfWithRowIndexUsingRDD(df: DataFrame, offset: Int = 1, colName: String = "row_num", inFront: Boolean = true): DataFrame = {
    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map(ln =>
        Row.fromSeq(
          (if (inFront) Seq(ln._2 + offset) else Seq())
            ++ ln._1.toSeq ++
            (if (inFront) Seq() else Seq(ln._2 + offset))
        )
      ),
      StructType(
        (if (inFront) Array(StructField(colName, LongType, false)) else Array[StructField]())
          ++ df.schema.fields ++
          (if (inFront) Array[StructField]() else Array(StructField(colName, LongType, false)))
      )
    )
  }

  def getSparkContext(runLocal: String, appName: String) = {

    val sc: SparkContext = if (runLocal.equalsIgnoreCase("local") || runLocal.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
      val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
      sparkConfig.set("spark.broadcast.compress", "false")
      sparkConfig.set("spark.shuffle.compress", "false")
      sparkConfig.set("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", "false")
      new SparkContext("local[1]", appName, sparkConfig)
    } else {
      val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
      new SparkContext(sparkConfig)
    }
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", false)
    sc
  }

  def createSchemaFrmStrDelValues(baseSchema: String): StructType = {
    return StructType(baseSchema.split(",").map(f => StructField(f, StringType, true)))
  }

  def getNamedArgs(args: Array[String]): Map[String, String] = {

    println("################### Input parameters are ############### " + args.toList)
    args.filter(line => line.contains("=")) //take only named arguments
      .map(x => {
      val key = x.substring(0, x.indexOf("="))
      val value = x.substring(x.indexOf("=") + 1)
      (key, if (value == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) null else value)
    }).toMap //convert to a map
  }

  def setLogLevels(level: Level, loggers: Seq[String]): Map[String, Level] = loggers.map(loggerName => {
    val logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerName)
    val prevLevel = logger.getLevel
    logger.setLevel(level)
    loggerName -> prevLevel
  }).toMap


  def pullDataFromCSVFile(sqlContext: SQLContext, isHeaderExist: Boolean, filePath: String, delimiter: String, csvSplit: String): DataFrame = {

    var csvDataFrame: DataFrame = null
    try {
      if (isHeaderExist) {
        csvDataFrame = sqlContext.read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .load(filePath)
      } else {

        if (csvSplit != null) {
          val schema = createSchemaFrmStrDelValues(csvSplit)

          csvDataFrame = sqlContext.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "false")
            .option("delimiter", delimiter)
            .option("inferSchema", "false")
            .schema(schema)
            .load(filePath)
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
        println("Unable to read the CSV file from the location " + filePath)
        ex.printStackTrace()
        throw ex
      }
    }
    csvDataFrame
  }



  def executeBatch(args: Array[String]) {

    val namedArgs = getNamedArgs(args)
    val runLocal = namedArgs("clusterORLocal")

    val sc: SparkContext = getSparkContext(runLocal, "Ml Pipeline")
    val csvOrHiveForTrain = namedArgs("csvOrHiveForTrain")
    val csvOrHiveForTest = namedArgs("csvOrHiveForTest")
    val locationToSaveModelData = namedArgs("locationToSaveModelData")
    val labelCol = namedArgs("labelCol")
    val featureCols = namedArgs("featureCols").toString.split(",").map(_.toLowerCase)
    val noOfNodes = namedArgs("noOfNodes").toInt
    val noOfIter = namedArgs("noOfIter").toInt

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    val trainDF = pullDataFromCSVFile(sqlContext, true, csvOrHiveForTrain, null, null)
    trainDF.printSchema()

    val testDF = pullDataFromCSVFile(sqlContext, true, csvOrHiveForTest, null, null)
    testDF.printSchema()

    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    var nonStringCols = ""
    var stringCols = ""

    for (field <- testDF.schema){
      val fieldName = field.name.trim
      val fieldDataType = field.dataType.typeName.trim

      if(featureCols.contains(fieldName.toLowerCase())){

        if(fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("integer") || fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("long") ||
          fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("DOUBLE") || fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("FLOAT") ||
          fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("DECIMAL"))
          nonStringCols +=fieldName+","
        else if(fieldDataType.equalsIgnoreCase("string"))
          stringCols +=fieldName+","
      }
    }

    if(nonStringCols.isEmpty && stringCols.isEmpty){
      throw new Exception("Check if Feature columns are empty")
    }

    val reqModel = Try {
      KMeansModel.load(locationToSaveModelData)
    }.getOrElse({
      val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(noOfNodes).setMaxIter(noOfIter)
      kmeans
    })

    //Build pipeline
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(buildDataPrepPipeLine(sqlContext, labelCol, stringCols, nonStringCols) ++ Array(reqModel))

    //Model generated and used to prepare data for model
    val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(trainDF)

    //predict using model using the prepared data thru the pipeline
    val testPredictions = pipelineModel.transform(testDF)
    testPredictions.show()
  }
}
```